# Webscraper bugging out from additional value

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

So I've completed my first webscraper, everything is working except one thing and I can't figure out why. My first scraping with the code `for x in range(1,6): getQuestions('bygg', x)` works fine, but then I add `for x in range(1,6): getQuestions('bygg', x) getQuestions('advokat', x)` and it just returns 0 (TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable) and the problem seems to be coming from my  `'nummer': item.find('a', {'class': 'link-body'})['href'],` since It says `'nummer': item.find('a', {'class': 'link-body'})['href'], TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

here is the full code

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'}

questionlist = []

def getQuestions(tag, page):
    url = f'https://www.merinfo.se/search?d=c&ap=1&emp=0%3A20&rev=0%3A100&who={tag}&bf=1&page={page}'
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    questions = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'box-white p-0 mb-4'})
    for item in questions:
        question = {
        'tag': tag,
        'title': item.find('a', {'class': 'link-primary'}).text,
        'link': item.find('a', {'class': 'link-primary'})['href'],
        'nummer': item.find('a', {'class': 'link-body'})['href'],
        'address': item.find('address', {'class': 'mt-2 mb-0'}).text,
        'RegÅr': item.find('div', {'class': 'col text-center'}).text,
        }
        questionlist.append(question)
    return

for x in range(1,6):
    getQuestions('bygg', x)
    getQuestions('advokat', x)

df = pd.DataFrame(questionlist)
df.to_excel('merinfo skrapare för bygg.xlsx')
print('LBC Marketing TM')
```

Last note, if I # out the `'nummer': item.find('a', {'class': 'link-body'})['href'],` it works fine but this is kinda the most important part lol.

Thankful for any help, best regards!

Comment: Please edit your question and give it a meaningful title. Questions are supposedly independent. If not, please explain how.

Comment: The problem is that item.find('a', {'class': 'link-body'}) is returning None

Answer (score 0):

As @AndyKnight mentioned, you are attempting access ['href'] on an item that is None.  You could add some sanity checks for None to help out. Something like:

```
def get_href_item(src_item, tag, class_name):
    href_item = src_item.find(tag, {"class": f"{class_name}"})
    if href_item is not None:
        href = href_item['href']
        if href is not None:
            return href
        else:
            return "HREF_NOT_FOUND"
```

Then you can use that method to get the 'nummer' values:

```
question = {
        'tag': tag,
        'title': item.find('a', {'class': 'link-primary'}).text,
        'link': item.find('a', {'class': 'link-primary'})['href'],
        'nummer': get_href_item(item, 'a', 'link-body'),
        'address': item.find('address', {'class': 'mt-2 mb-0'}).text,
        'RegÅr': item.find('div', {'class': 'col text-center'}).text,
        }
```

You will probably want to add similar sanity checks for None for all of the values you are searching for.

Comment: The thing is that the href cant be None since when I search Bygg instead of Advokat it works fine and it has the same HTML code, that's the confusing part.

Comment: @CavTGpunk I modified your code as I outlined in my answer above and it runs without encountering the `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` error.  Running your code as is, and the error occurs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I just figured out how to implement the code you gave me {lol} and it worked! You're amazing.